# NextJS issue with server side rendering with react-d3-tree

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, react-d3

To start off, I have looked at issue number [40](https://github.com/bkrem/react-d3-tree/issues/40) and [95](https://github.com/bkrem/react-d3-tree/issues/95) on the [react-d3-tree github](https://github.com/bkrem/react-d3-tree)
I don't see anything on StackOverflow that would help me. I am trying to implement the parseJSON method so I can take my own JSON file from the project folder and then generate a tree diagram.

Let's start from what I did in the beginning. I copy pasted the example code which worked for 2 seconds before crashing. Reason? Server Side Rendering. Great, so then I find [this from NextJS](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) which allows me to disable SSR for some components. Hey, now the example code is working. Let's try the [example code where they use external data](https://github.com/bkrem/react-d3-tree#external-data-sources)! Nope, it can't find the parseJSON method. I have no idea what to do, can't find anything to fix this. I am trying to import this function that has some issue with SSR, but because it isn't a component I am not able to import it using dynamic, and I can't import normally because it causes a "window is not defined" error because of SSR.
The following are my main two files.

**DynamicComponent.js [Version 1]**

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const Tree = dynamic(
  () => import('react-d3-tree'),
  { ssr: false },
);

export default Tree;
```

**DynamicComponent.js [Version 2]**

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

export const Tree = dynamic(
  () => import('react-d3-tree'),
  { ssr: false },
);

export const treeUtil = dynamic(
  () => import('react-d3-tree/src/util'),
  { ssr: false },
);
```

**Diagram/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Tree, treeUtil } from '../DynamicComponent';

const myTreeData = require('../fakeData.json');

class Diagram extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      data: undefined,
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    treeUtil.parseJSON(myTreeData)
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ data });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        id="treeWrapper"
        style={{ width: '50em', height: '20em' }}
      >
        <Tree data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Diagram;
```

**Error I Get with Version 1**

```
ReferenceError: treeUtil is not defined
```

**Error I Get with Version 2**

```
TypeError: _DynamicComponent__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.treeUtil.parseJSON is not a function
```

Please StackOverflow, you're my only hope.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem with Cytoscape, a similar library (but specifically for graph-network visualization). It took lots of trial and error, but the solution was:

1. import the component dynamically
2. remove the import JSON and inline it into a js file. For some stupid reason, that worked for me and was the magic fix. (how big was your JSON file?) Worse-case try copying & pasting into the component itself.

For your component try this:

```
// convert fakeData.json to fakeData.js
export default {...fake data here };
```

---

```
import React from 'react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import myTreeData from 'fakeData';

const Tree = dynamic(
  () => import('./dynamicComponent'),
   { ssr: false }
);

// you can also delineate a loading component;


// converted to hooks for '21
 const Diagram = () => {
 
   const [data,setData] = useState({});


  useEffect(() => {
    treeUtil.parseJSON(myTreeData)
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
      })
  },[treeUtil,myTreeData,setData]);


    return (
      <div
        id="treeWrapper"
        style={{ width: '50em', height: '20em' }}
      >
        <Tree data={data} />
      </div>
    );
  }

export default Diagram;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `treeUtil` is not a react component, so you can't use `dynamic` to import it. Just import it normally may be work.

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

export const Tree = dynamic(
  () => import('react-d3-tree'),
  { ssr: false },
);

export { default as treeUtil } from 'react-d3-tree/src/util';
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, seems like a syntax issue. 
I got this error:
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ";"
at the '=' sign.

Comment: Sor, i got a typo. How about change to `export { default as treeUtil } from 'react-d3-tree/src/util'` works ?